# How is “in but few” used in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Sentence taken from [Tchaikovsky’s textbook of Harmony, page 55 (middle of the page)](https://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=AwrE19HaCetgjhsAsRZx.9w4;_ylu=Y29sbwNiZjEEcG9zAzEEdnRpZAMEc2VjA3Ny/RV=2/RE=1626045019/RO=10/RU=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bestmusicteacher.com%2Fdownload%2FTchaikovsky_HarmonyTextbook_Eng.pdf/RK=2/RS=S5Xonw0hX.LWURNPC73XrKNVeqU-)

> “The chord of the sixth and fourth can be effectively employed in but few cases.  These are as follows:”

What confuses me is “in but few cases”.

Is this sentence indicating: (1.) “The following” are the effectively employable cases?  Or (2.) These are the cases where it cannot be effectively employed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locked or would comment. It's an old-fashioned way of saying *in only a few cases*, so what follows is a list of cases where this chord *can* be used effectively. In this case you can solve your grammatical problem with a piano!

Comment: This exact 'answer' was given in a comment, but has since _been disappeared_. This usage of 'but' has been addressed in a previous thread.